# Teaser of full html pages without layout

Tags: 7, views, theming, blocks

I have a block/view that shows teasers of the latest 3 articles.. This articles are full html, it contains layout (build with a WYSIWYG)..

On the homepage, I create a block that shows the latest 3 articles.. I can give it CSS-layout..

[image: Block]

But because it's build with the WYSIWYG, there are extra html-tags (span, a, p, ...) in the teaser, which can be different every time. The problem is that it overwrites the default layout for the teasers..

[image: html of the teaser]

I just want to keep the clean text on the frontpage block, and full-html on the detail page. How can I manage it?

Normally I should use strip_tags(); in PHP to remove html.. But how can I do it only for that specific block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the body field and trim it.

[image]

Now in your web directory, go to `/sites/all/themes/yourtheme/` folder and in **template.php** add the following code:

```
function yourtheme_preprocess_views_view_fields($vars){

  if ($vars['view']->name == "view_name" && $vars['view']->current_display == "block_1") {
    $vars['fields']['body']->content = strip_tags($vars['fields']['body']->content);
  }

}
```

- replace **yourtheme** with the actual name of your theme
- replace **view_name** with the name of your view.
- replace **block_1** with the [machine name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbNIb.jpg) of your view. If yours happens to be block_1 then leave it the same.

In Drupal, clear/flush your cache to see the changes.

Then add the other fields you want on your view, title, post date? comment link? etc... basically you create your own teaser.

**PS**: You can [add classes to your fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvhMy.jpg), if you need to use css on them.

Comment: I'm trying this.. So far so good.. But like you said, it ends stripping everything.. Now trying part 2.

Comment: I used the whole solution, it works like a charm! I use classes, but inline css overwrites it always ;-). Thnx!